# Joining 3 tables & inserting in a 4th table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am joining 3 tables - `items` , `sales` , & `purchase`.

And then, inserting the combined data into a 4th table `FULL_DETAIL_OF_ITEMS`.

`ITEMS` table has columns : `ITEM_CD, ITEM_NM, COM_CD, SALE_RT, PURCH_RT, MRP`

`SALES` table has columns : `ITEM_CD, ITEM_NM, SALE_QTY`

`PURCHASE` table has columns : `ITEM_CD, ITEM_NM, PURCH_QTY`

`FULL_DETAIL_OF_ITEMS` table has columns :

```
ITEM_CD, ITEM_NM, COM_CD, SALE_RT, PURCH_RT, MRP, SALE_QTY, PURCH_QTY
```

The query is:

```
insert into FULL_DETAIL_OF_ITEMS
  SELECT
     Items.Item_CD, 
     Items.Item_NM , 
     ITEMS.COM_CD, 
     ITEMS.SALE_RT, 
     ITEMS.PURCH_RT, 
     ITEMS.MRP, 
     SALES.SALE_QTY, 
     PURCHASE.PURCH_QTY
  FROM items
  JOIN sales on ITEMS.ITEM_CD = sales.ITEM_CD 
  JOIN purchase on items.ITEM_CD = purchase.ITEM_CD
```

`Items` table is filled but `sales` & `purchase` tables are empty, so on executing the above query nothing happens? Why so?

At least it should insert rest of the columns from the items table into the 4th table.

It finds that in sales table - `sale_qty` , & in purchase table, `purch_qty` is empty, so it should fill null in these columns in the final table & fill rest of the columns as they are picked from item table which consists data so it should fill that.

But its not doing so?

According to the definition of JOIN, ITEM_CD in item table is not matching with the ITEM_CD column of the sales & purchase table as it is empty in both, so this is the reason.

But I want that rest of the data is inserted in the 4th table, then is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change those `join` statements to `left join`.

By default, a `join` is an "inner join", which means that only rows that exist on both sides of the join will be included. A "left join" includes *all* rows on the "left" side of the join.

Example:

```
from items
left join sales on ITEMS.ITEM_CD =sales.ITEM_CD
left join purchase on items.ITEM_CD =purchase.ITEM_CD
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir,       " left join sales on ITEMS.ITEM_CD =sales.ITEM_CD  "          -- for this code:                                                  how is the actual joining done?according to me , as it is left join,  join is in between & the items table is on its left, so it would include all the rows from the items table  & on the right is sales table.

Comment: @sqlchild that's right - all items rows will be included, and where there is no sales row, the sales columns will be filled with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize your query using a `select into` statement which will, by default, creates a new table at run time.

```
select  Items.Item_CD,Items.Item_NM,Items.COM_CD,Items.Mrp,Items.Purchase_RT,Items.Sale_RT,
      purchase.Purchase_QTY,Sales.Sale_QTY
into full_details_of_items
from Items
inner join purchase
inner join Sales 
on purchase.Item_CD=Sales.Item_CD
on items.Item_CD=purchase.Item_CD
```